# How to show all objects with same field value as 1 result and aggregate another field in django

Tags: python, django

it is a little complicated, here is how my model looks like:

```py
class Warehouse(models.Model):
    in_move = "in"
    out_move = "out"
    move_type_choices = (
        (in_move, _('دخول')),
        (out_move, _('خروج'))
    )
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    move_type = models.CharField(choices=move_type_choices, max_length=120)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

what I need to do is :

- A queryset like `warehouse.objects.filter(branch=spicific_branch)`
- group it by the item name **so it shows all the queryset that have
  same `item` as one result**
- Get the sum of the field `quantity`
- Define if it `in` or `out` move to get the current quantity inside
  the warehouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
branch_filter = warehouse.objects.filter(branch__name='spicific_branch')
item_sum = warehouse.objects.values('item__name' ).annotate(total_qty=Sum('quantity'))
```

Comment: Can't I perform the `.filter()` part in the same line with `.values()` ?